# WSL2 Ubuntu Windows 11: node version reverts to 16 after `nvm use 18` after closing/reopening terminal

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code, nvm

On my Windows 11 machine, using WSL2 and an Ubuntu distro, if I run `node -v` after launching the terminal (either the standalone terminal or the one integrated into VS Code), it says I'm running version 16.

If I run `nvm use 18`, it (correctly) switches my Node version to 18.

However, if I close the terminal and re-open it, it reverts to version 16.

I have tried `nvm alias default 18`, but that doesn't cause v18 to persist.  I have also tried closing all my terminals (standalone and VS Code), opening each one at a time, and running `nvm alias default`, but to no effect.

Is there a way to make my terminals always launch with the node version set to 18?